# Does REST make sense for an event collecting API?

Tags: rest, events, api-design

I'm building an API for collecting events from an ecommerce site. The data flow, besides authentication and HTTP response codes, will be entirely from client to server.

**Does it make sense to design such an API in a RESTful way?**

For example, I'm not sure if I get much from URL endpoints representing resources. For instance, when a user on the ecommerce site goes to a new page, I'd like the API to be notified, and sent all the user data that has changed. RESTfully, I'd have to do it at an endpoint like `/pageloads`, `/webpages` or maybe `/users` since I'm interested not only in the page data but the user's too. Not quite RESTfully, the following seems more natural: `/pageloadEvents` along with other events represented like this. I'm saying "not quite RESTfully" because such endpoints don't seem to represent real resources, such as the web pages, users, etc, underneath.

Additionally, because of the communication going only from client to server, I won't have any need for the REST verb `GET`. In other words, the server is just a listener here. Perhaps this one sided communication is REST-wise OK, but looking around, I get a sense that that's a bit unusual.

Many thanks!

Comment: Sure, it's pretty unusual but you still can apply the REST principles here and build a RESTful API to solve your problem. I can't see why you shouldn't do that way. Perhaps, you should create only one resource named "events" and allow only the POST method on this resource. I don't know, I don't have a deep understanding of your system, so I'm just guessing. :)